# openresty : problems with the init_by_lua directive (getting "directive is not allowed here")

Tags: nginx, openresty

I'm trying to use the init_by_lua directive : https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module#init_by_lua

and nginx fails to start, with this message in the log :

```
2014/04/08 17:33:53 [emerg] 2105#0: "init_by_lua" directive is not allowed here in /genap/genap-nginx.conf:6
```

the nginx conf file is :

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log logs/error.log;

init_by_lua 'local zaz = 4321';


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
    server {

        lua_code_cache off;
        listen 80;
        location / {
            default_type text/html;
            content_by_lua_file /vagrant/genap_host_proxy/content.lua;

        }
    }
}
```

I've tries putting init_by_lua in the http and server block, and I get the same error init_by_lua

Comment: It works in the http context. Are you 100% you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

`init_by_lua` is only allowed in `http` content: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#init_by_lua

```
http {
    init_by_lua '
        require "resty.core"
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put it inside the http { ... } block?

```
  http {
      init_by_lua 'local zaz = 4321';
      server { ... }
    }
```